# http request header with special character java

Tags: java, request, http-headers, postman, http-get

I'm trying to use httpGet with token that have illegal character in header.
I got error 401 in java , and in Postman i succeeded to get response.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SF_DEFAULT_HOST + REPORT_URL);
header.add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);;
JSONObject jsonUserInfo = WebClient.fetch(httpGet);
```

in this case the token equal to => 00D90000000sYg0!ARkAQGLOKJhVhT3O_7JnIZTP3UGctmzW9jXa3HtD6li8bS_eEwhhQTRfsC_ayoQLgcST6fX6p6jU49MQpe.lGEZxFLuzccLn

[image: Picture from postman with request success response.]

Picture from postman with request success response.

Comment: You MUST base64 your token to make it suitable for HTTP protocol.

Comment: @JerryChin
i tried , also if you look at postman request it's nod encoded
,also some of the users that have token without spical charachters it work fine .

Comment: First send GET in java, then you should receive 401, now send your authentication header with based64 token, see what happens, don't forget to decode the token on the server side!

Comment: i tried this 
       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SF_DEFAULT_HOST + REPORT_URL);
   JSONObject jsonUserInfo = WebClient.fetch(httpGet);
   String base64 = com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encodeAsString(accessToken.getBytes());
   header.add("Authorization", "OAuth " + base64);


still failure

Comment: Do you decode the token when you receive it on the server?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno , this request sent to salesforce api ,i didn't see in thier documntaion that they request encoded toke, also if you look at the pictures you will see that the same requets from postman succsed without sending encoded token.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the token with non US-ASCII characters, this is the reason of error you are facing. you need to encode the header before adding it in the request.

Java class to do the encoding is java.net.URLEncoder.

Note: RFC 2616 says you can ONLY use US-ASCII in HTTP headers. Other characters have to be encoded.

In C# there is direct method to add token with non US-ASCII characters.

HttpClient queryClient = new HttpClient();

queryClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);